# What happens to the dynamite when you die?

Tags: bang

In BANG!, if a player has the dynamite in front of them when they die, what happens to the dynamite?

Does that change when someone's special skill is to receive the cards of dead people?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dynamite is discarded unless the dynamite didn't kill the dead player AND Vulture Sam is playing.

From the Bang! [consolidated FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/7676/bang-consolidated-faq-doc):

> **If the Dynamite explodes eliminating a player, does the character Vulture Sam draw the Dynamite along with all other cards of the player eliminated?**
>
> No. To complete the effect of the Dynamite you have to discard it after it explodes. So when Vulture Sam gets all the cards of the player killed, the Dynamite is already in the discard pile.

So,

1. If the Dynamite hasn't exploded, Vulture Sam picks it up as normal (since he takes all cards from the dead player). From the [rulebook](http://www.davincigames.net/bang/bang_rules.pdf):

   > whenever a character is
   > eliminated from the game,
   > Sam takes all the cards
   > that player had in his
   > hand and in play, and adds them to
   > his hand.
2. If the Dynamite did explode (killing the player), Vulture Sam does not pick it up, since it has been discarded.
3. If Vulture Sam (or similar) isn't playing, then the dynamite is discarded along with all other cards of the dead player. Again, from the [rulebook](http://www.davincigames.net/bang/bang_rules.pdf):

   > When you are
   > eliminated from the game, show your role card and discard all the cards you
   > have in hand and in play.